# How to connect node to itself using Relay Connection (Graphene Python)?

Tags: python, graphql, relay, graphene-python

I'm new to Relay and trying to follow along with the docs. In the below fragment, it seems they are querying on a user and then getting the users friends. I presume the same model is being used for the queried user and their friends.

```
fragment FriendsListComponent_user on User
@refetchable(queryName: "FriendsListPaginationQuery") {
    name
    friends(first: $count, after: $cursor)
    @connection(key: "FriendsList_user_friends") {
        edges {
            node {
                name
                age
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I can't figure out how to create this connection in my Graphene schema.
I have this simple user class:

```
class UserNode(graphene.ObjectType):
    class Meta:
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )

    name = graphene.String()
    friends = relay.ConnectionField(FriendConnection)
```

and this connection:

```
class FriendConnection(relay.Connection):
    class Meta:
        node = UserNode
```

but none of them can go before the other!

Am I missing something here? How would I define such a connection, if it's even possible?